# MC Connect / disconnect the integration

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

When a SFMC/SF connector has been badly implemented, would it be OK to disconnect the integration et do it again?
If yes, how ?
And then, should we implement the connector from scratch (as if the platforms have never been connected)?
What would be the impact on the SFMC platform by doing this?

Thanks

Regards

Ludivine

Answer (score 0):

If the integrated data has not been used in SFMC yet, then you can proceed with disconnect. If used, then you have to pause all automations/Journeys which involves Queries, Import Definitions,Salesforce Data entry source etc. that are using the integrated objects and then disconnect.

For disconnect and reconnect using SF credentials, Go to Setup => Salesforce Integration => click Disconnect/Connect Account.

> **Note** -
>
> 1. All the records from the Contact object are synced after integration. So if you disconnect, these will still be part of
>    'Contact Builder' and the source for each, will get updated to
>    'Unspecified'. Delete these records through 'Contact Deletion'
>    process, so it does not count against your contact limit.
> 2. You have to start from scratch (adding objects, fields & filter conditions).
> 3. While reconnecting, make sure not to keep any active sessions in browser (logged into incorrect SF org)